# how to save changes made in my .rb program in the terminal?

Tags: ruby, crud

I'm really new to this but I’ve written a small program that will CRUD a movie to a list the only problem is it is not saving the changes made. how can I make this happen?

```
error = "movie not found"
movies = {
    Mazerunner: 1
}
error = "movie not found"
puts "welcome to CrudMovies"
puts "enter a command"
puts "type add to add a movie to the list"
choice = gets.chomp.downcase

case choice
when "add"
    puts "what movie would you like to add"
        title = gets.chomp
    if movies[title.to_sym].nil?
        puts "what would you like the rating of #{rating} (1-4)to be?"
        rating = gets.chomp
        movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
        puts "#{title} was added with a rating of #{rating}"
    else
        puts "that movie already exists"
end
when "update"
    puts "what movie would you like to update? (case sensitive)"
        title = gets.chomp
    if movies[title.to_sym].nil?
    puts "#{error}"
else
    puts "what is the movie rating would you like to update?"
    movies[title.to symb] = rating.to_i
    puts "#{title}'s rating has been updated to #{rating}"
end
when "display"
    movies.each do |x, y|
    puts "#{x} Rating:#{y}"
end
when "destroy"
    puts "what movie would you like to erase?"
        title = gets.chomp
    if movies[title.to_sym].nil?
        puts "#{error}"
    else
        movies.delete(title.to_sym)
    puts "the movie no longer exists"
end
    else
        puts "command not recognized"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that by "Save" you mean stored in the `movies` hash. The answer to that is that is it is in fact being stored. Only your script exits after you perform an operation, so you never get to see the updated `movies`.

To see the desired result you're going to want to wrap the majority of this in an infinite loop to prevent the script from naturally exiting.

Consider the following as an example:

```
store = []
while true
  puts "Enter something:"
  choice = gets.chomp
  store.push choice
  puts "Your choices so far are: #{store.inspect}"
end
```

Comment: do you know how those changes could be made permanently to the .rb file where the movies hash is

Comment: Answer updated to show an example store, in this case a simple Array